# configuring nginx server to store the static images and html

Tags: nginx

I want to configure the nginx server in my windows7 PC.For storing images and html files.
    I followed up the following  steps:
    1.I downloaded the nginx-1.2.9 and unziped into c:\ filder.
    2. created one folder "data" and within 'data" folder created another two folders say "WWW" and "images". 
    3.Keeping all images in the "images"folder .and .html file in folder "WWW".
    4.Now started the nginx server using command C:\nginx-1.2.9>start nginx

```
5.Made changes in nginx.conf file.`    
    #server {
    #location / {
    #    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0:8080;
    #}

    #location /images/ {
    #    root /C:/data/images;
    # }


}
```

Not able to access images and html page.
    Please help me to solving this problem. I'm sure doing mistake in config file only..
    Thanks in Advance,
    Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented the configuration data.First remove all the # from your configuration file.Then use the below code inside the server {}

```
    location / {
    root data/www;
}

location /images/ {
    root data;
}
```

Note- the location of the static file inside your nginx root folder should be the (root+location) data and the access of the file should be "location" data. e.g from the first location configuration the static file should present inside the folder "data/WWW/" and in the second location configuration the static file should present inside the folder "data/images/".

```
URL                               folder inside nginx home path
-----                            --------------------------
localhost/hello.html              data/WWW/hello.html
localhost/images/img1.png         data/images/img1.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your `nginx.conf` file found at `<Nginx Install Dir>\conf` folder.
Define a new `location` in your related `server` part. Example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    
    location /images/ {
        alias 'C:/My Images/';
    }       
    ...
```

Save your `nginx.conf` file and restart Nginx. You can also apply the changes via

```
nginx -s reload
```

in the command prompt.

To access your images, go to the address in the browser

http://host:80/images/image1.png

You can also define a location involving *nested folders* like

```
location /images/icons/ {
    alias 'C:/My Images/My Icons/';
}
```

A `location` in the `nginx.conf` file is a link/map to a physical directory containing your static files. It corresponds to the *virtual directory* concept in IIS.

Also note that you need to enclose the path (next to the `alias`) with single quotes (') if the path contains spaces or you will get an internal server error when you restart/reload the Nginx server.